# SocketError: Failed to open TCP connection to docker service when executing docker-compose file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, service, docker-compose

Here's my docker-compose file. I have a **scraper** service feeding a rails api (data_api):

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis-server:
    image: redis
    restart: always
  scraper:
    image: davidgeismar/artifacts-scraper:without-db
    command: "bundle exec rake scrape_sources:scrape\"[['christies'],nil,[2019]]\""
    volumes:
      - ./logs/artifacts_scraper:/usr/src/artifacts_scraper/log
    environment:
      - REDIS_URL=redis://redis-server:6379/0
      - ARTIFACTS_ENV=docker_development
      - DATA_API_BASE=http://data_api:3000
    depends_on:
      - data_api
      - redis-server
  data_api:
    volumes:
      - ./logs/artifacts_data_api:/artifacts_data_api/log
    image: davidgeismar/artifacts_data_api:latest
    command: 'rails server -b 0.0.0.0'
    environment:
      - RAILS_ENV=docker_development
      - SECRET_KEY_BASE=docker_development_secret
  sidekiq:
    volumes:
      - ./logs/sidekiq/scraper:/usr/src/artifacts_scraper/log
    image: davidgeismar/artifacts-scraper:without-db
    command: 'bundle exec sidekiq -r ./artifacts_scraper.rb 2>&1 | tee ./log/sidekiq.log'
    environment:
      - REDIS_URL=redis://redis-server:6379/0
      - ARTIFACTS_ENV=docker_development
      - DATA_API_BASE=http://data_api:3000
    depends_on:
      - redis-server
      - data_api
```

I execute it with  `docker-compose pull && docker-compose up --build`

However data_api keeps on exiting telling me :

```
data_api_1      | A server is already running. Check /artifacts_data_api/tmp/pids/server.pid.
```

event though in my dockerfile for that service I have :

```
RUN rm -f ./tmp/pids/server.pid
```

On top of that I get `SocketError: Failed to open TCP connection to data_api:3000 (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)` for the **scraper** service which Im unable to understand why it happens.

All containers are accessible and pullable from dockerhub.
The code for the **scraper** service :
https://github.com/davidgeismar/artifacts-scraper/tree/removing-db

and for the data_api:
https://github.com/davidgeismar/artifacts_data_api